# I've declared 'started'=False where in the nested if condition the printed results are inversed to what I expected

Tags: python-3.x, boolean, boolean-logic

```
started=False
while True:
    command=input("Enter your command: ").lower()
    if command=='start':
        if started:
            print("Car is has successfully started. Engines on!")
        else:
            started=True
            print("Car has already started!")
    
    else:
        print("Enter correct command")
```

Here, I've presented to you the part of the program where I'm stuck. Hypothetically in the nested loop, if the variable 'started' is false(as it is set), it should print the first print statement but it does not. It somehow prints the else print statement. Basically the results reversed to what I wanted. I've got the boolean logic wrong. Please to explain why this is happening in detail.

Comment: This is not a nested loop btw, and which if statement are you stuck at?

Comment: since you need your `if` to evaluate `True` when your `started` value is` False` ,you should use `not` operater..that is `if not started:`

Comment: You just have your `print` statements mixed up. `if started:` you want it to read `"Car has already started!"`. Switch your `print` statements around and it will work as intended.